# Does L-theanine affect caffeine's half-life?

Tags: health, caffeine, chemistry

Does consuming L-theanine with caffeine, either in drink (like *matcha*) or in pill form, affect the half-life of caffeine?

I have heard something like *"L-theanine slows caffeine absorption"*, so I am inclined to assume that caffeine's half-life may increase, but I have no idea if one can jump to that conclusion. And I cannot find anything on this topic.

Comment: Isn't this more of a chemistry (how do these compounds interact?) or biology (how do these compounds interact in the human body?) question?

Comment: Yes it is. I did not fund such forums but also found the Medical Sciences StackExchange, and asked there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about coffee and the [cross-site dupe op med.SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/25314) already received an answer.